# isnumeric() について

Tags: python

string to integerという問題で、

```
class Solution(object):
    def myAtoi(self, str):
        """
        :type str: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        if (str.isnumeric) and str!="":
            return int(str)
        else:
            return 0
```

と書いたが、試しにinputで"++"を入力すると、

Line 8: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '++'
が出て、つまり、"+"はisnumericはTrueと判断されている。

isnumericについて検索しましたが、数字だとTrueと書いていました。
しかし計算に関連する符号、たとえば+,-,%,/もnumericに含むのでしょうか？
それともこのコードの他の部分が間違っているのでしょうか？
教えていただけないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `(str.isnumeric) or str!=""` は `str.isnumeric() and str!=""` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: すみません。タイピングミスしました。andです。　しかし同じく結果はline8で同じエラーが発生します。

Comment: `str.isnumeric()` にしていますか？(メソッドの呼び出しなので `()` が必要です)

Comment: なるほどです！解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function reference != function call

`foo.isnumeric` -> 関数参照
`foo.isnumeric()` -> 関数呼出し

```
>>> '23'.isnumeric
<built-in method isnumeric of str object at 0x7feb87baa880>
>>> '23'.isnumeric()
True
```

`Solution.myAtoi()`はただ`a_to_i()`になります*:

```
>>> def a_to_i(s):
...     if s.isnumeric():
...         return int(s)
...     else:
...         return 0
... 
>>> a_to_i('234453')
234453
>>> a_to_i('v%87eb8b')
0
>>> a_to_i('')
0
>>> a_to_i('27.3')
0
>>> # あれっ！？
```

float型も受け入れる方は:

```
>>> def a_to_n(s):
...     if s.isnumeric():
...         return int(s)
...     else:
...         try:
...             return float(s)
...         except ValueError:
...             return 0
... 
>>> a_to_n('3243.245')
3243.245
>>> a_to_n('3243.2452.24523')
0
>>> a_to_n('Frank')
0
>>> a_to_n('25')
25
```

[string].isnumeric()の出力:

```
>>> ''.isnumeric()
False
>>> '254231'.isnumeric()
True
>>> '24.143'.isnumeric()
False
>>> # \(O.o)/ 危ないそれ！
...
>>> for x in range(32, 126):     
...     z = chr(x)               
...     print(z, z.isnumeric())  
... 
  False
! False
" False
# False
$ False
% False
& False
' False
( False
) False
* False
+ False
, False
- False
. False
/ False
0 True
1 True
2 True
3 True
4 True
5 True
6 True
7 True
8 True
9 True
: False
; False
< False
= False
> False
? False
@ False
A False
B False
C False
D False
E False
F False
G False
H False
I False
J False
K False
L False
M False
N False
O False
P False
Q False
R False
S False
T False
U False
V False
W False
X False
Y False
Z False
[ False
\ False
] False
^ False
_ False
` False
a False
b False
c False
d False
e False
f False
g False
h False
i False
j False
k False
l False
m False
n False
o False
p False
q False
r False
s False
t False
u False
v False
w False
x False
y False
z False
{ False
| False
} False
```

（* Python != Java. あるclassとそのclassのinstanceとは違いがなければclassじゃなくてただのfunctionを作った方が良いです。selfを使わないmethodはJavaの"static method"か"class method"と同じですが、Pythonではclass methodの方はあんまり使いません。なぜならpython moduleは陰のclassなので、class methodはinner class methodになります。）

Answer (score 3):

コメントにある通りメソッド呼び出しにしないといけないので、`str.isnumeric()` とカッコを補うべきです。

それとは別の話として、`isnumeric()` メソッドは予想外の文字列に対して True を返しうるので注意が必要です。たとえば：

```
>>> "123".isnumeric()  # これは普通
True
>>> "１２３".isnumeric()  # 全角数字
True
>>> "一万二千三十四".isnumeric()  # 漢数字
True
>>> "1¾".isnumeric()  # 分数
True
>>> "Ⅲ".isnumeric()  # ローマ数字
True
```

なぜなら Unicode で[数字扱い](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode)されている文字たちから成る文字列なら、`isnumeric()` は True を返してしまうからです。以下、[`isnumeric()` のドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric)から引用します。

> 文字列中の全ての文字が数を表す文字で、かつ 1 文字以上あるなら真を、そうでなければ偽を返します。数を表す文字は、数字と、Unicode の数値プロパティを持つ全ての文字を含みます。たとえば U+2155 (VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH)。正式には、数を表す文字は、プロパティ値 Numeric_Type=Digit、 Numeric_Type=Decimal または Numeric_Type=Numeric を持つものです。

上に挙げた例の中には当然のように、`isnumeric()` が True だが `int()` が失敗するものが含まれます。したがって `int()` が成功するかどうかの条件分岐に `isnumeric()` を使うべきではありません。

**解決策**：「`int()` が失敗したかどうか」で判別したいだけなら、[`int()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#int) が送出する ValueError を補足して失敗判定すると良いでしょう。

```
>>> # 実装例
... def myAtoi(s):
...     try:
...         return int(s)
...     except ValueError:
...         return 0  # ここにお好みのエラー処理を書く
...
>>> # 動作例
... myAtoi("123")
123
>>> myAtoi("-123")
-123
>>> myAtoi("")
0
>>> myAtoi("1.23")
0
>>> myAtoi("１２３")
123
>>> myAtoi("一万二千三十四")
0
>>> myAtoi("   123   ")  # 前後に空白が入っていても良い
123
>>> myAtoi("0010")  # Python の整数リテラルとしては 0010 は違法
10
```

判定をもっと厳しく、たとえば「半角数字とプラス・マイナスだけ受け付けたい」という風にするなら、それ専用のバリデーション処理を書くことになります。